# Why use **kwds instead of a specific named argument in a function definition?

Tags: python

The function definition below comes from the itertools recipes page (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def random_product(*args, **kwds):
    "Random selection from itertools.product(*args, **kwds)"
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    return tuple(random.choice(pool) for pool in pools)
```

The function signature would seem to be more readable written with the "repeat" argument specified explicitly, e.g.

```
def random_product(*args, repeat=1)
```

But I'm guessing there is a reason why it is written using the general idiom. Can anyone explain?

Comment: It's not actually part of `itertools`; it's just a suggestion how to implement such a function. Most likely, some body wrote it like that for no particular reason, then copied it into the documentation as-is.

Comment: Why have you cross-posted this? What was unclear about Martijn's answer [on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264976/python-recipe-question-use-of-kwds-instead-of-specific-named-argument-in-iter)? `def random_product(*args, repeat=1):` **isn't valid syntax** in Python 2.x. Note that `*args, repeat=1` is used [in the 3.x docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes), where it is valid.

Comment: The question is phrased as being generic in the title, but reading it, it's about a very specific case. Is the intent to inquire about the general case, or the specific case? (The latter is, as previously noted, already answered elsewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can't have keyword arguments after `*args` in Python 2.x, it's a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> def random_product(*args, repeat=1):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The only option is therefore to use `**kwds` and extract `repeat`, if present, from the resulting dictionary.

By contrast, in the [3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), `random_product` is implemented as you suggest, as that syntax *is* valid in Python 3:

```
def random_product(*args, repeat=1):
    ...
```

Comment: This is CW as Martijn [already answered it on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/264980/110531), but you can't close cross-site duplicates; go upvote there if you liked this!

Answer (score 1):

The original code was probably copied from a library function `def product(*args, **kwds):` and kept this way to look similar to the `product()` function. Plus `def random_product(*args, repeat=1)` isn't valid in Python 2.x (kudos go to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) for pointing this out).

Other than that, I don't see a reason to use `**kwds` here. If this was a library function that changed over time, it might be there so old arguments would be still supported but even then, I'd prefer `, repeat=1, **kwds)` to document which arguments are still supported and which are ignored.

To support my point, the next example reads `def random_permutation(iterable, r=None):`.

Comment: But unlike `def random_product(*args, repeat=1)`, `def random_permutation(iterable, r=None)` is **valid Python 2.x syntax**.